# How to handle buffered Read-Write Stream(s) to peers in golang using libp2p?

Tags: go, stream, p2p, libp2p

I am following this tutorial:

https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-examples/tree/master/chat-with-mdns

In a short form, it:

1. configures a p2p host
2. sets a default handler function for incoming connections
   (3. not necessary)
3. and opens a stream to the connecting peers:

`stream, err := host.NewStream(ctx, peer.ID, protocol.ID(cfg.ProtocolID))`

Afterwards, there is a buffer stream/read-write variable created:

`rw := bufio.NewReadWriter(bufio.NewReader(stream), bufio.NewWriter(stream))`

Now this stream is used to send and receive data between the peers. This is done using two goroutine functions that have rw as an input:

`go writeData(rw)`
`go readData(rw)`

My problems are:

1. I want to send data to my peers and need feedback from them:
   e.g. in rw there is a question and they need to answer yes/no. How can I transfer back this answer and process it (enable some interaction)?
2. The data I want to send in rw is not always the same. Sometimes it's a string containing only a name, sometimes it's a string containing a whole block etc. How can I distinguish?

I thought about those solutions. But I am new to golang, so maybe you have a better one:

- do I need a new stream for every different content:
  `stream, err := host.NewStream(ctx, peer.ID, protocol.ID(cfg.ProtocolID))`
- do I need to open more buffered rw varibales for every different content:
  `rw := bufio.NewReadWriter(bufio.NewReader(stream), bufio.NewWriter(stream))`
- are there any other solutions?

Thank you for any help to solve this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `readData` does from your tuto:

```golang
func readData(rw *bufio.ReadWriter) {
    for {
        str, err := rw.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from buffer")
            panic(err)
        }

        if str == "" {
            return
        }
        if str != "\n" {
            // Green console colour:    \x1b[32m
            // Reset console colour:    \x1b[0m
            fmt.Printf("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m> ", str)
        }

    }
}
```

It basically reads the stream until it finds a `\n`, which is a new line character and prints it to stdout.

The `writeData`:

```golang
func writeData(rw *bufio.ReadWriter) {
    stdReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        fmt.Print("> ")
        sendData, err := stdReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from stdin")
            panic(err)
        }

        _, err = rw.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", sendData))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing to buffer")
            panic(err)
        }
        err = rw.Flush()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error flushing buffer")
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

It reads data from stdin, so you can type messages, and writes this to the `rw` and flushes it. This kind of enables a sort of tty chat.
If it works correctly you should be able to start at least two peers and communicate through stdin.

You shouldn't recreate new `rw` for new content. You can reuse the existing one until you close it. From the tuto's code, a new `rw` is created for each new peer.

---

Now a tcp stream does not work as an http request with a request and a response corresponding to that request. So if you want to send something, and get the response to that specific question, you could send a message of this format:

```
[8 bytes unique ID][content of the message]\n
```

And when you receive it, you parse it, prepare the response and send it with the same format, so that you can match messages, creating a sort of request/response communication.

You can do something like that:

```golang
func sendMsg(rw *bufio.ReadWriter, id int64, content []byte) error {
        // allocate our slice of bytes with the correct size 4 + size of the message + 1
        msg := make([]byte, 4 + len(content) + 1)

        // write id 
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(msg, uint64(id))

        // add content to msg
        copy(msg[13:], content)

        // add new line at the end
        msg[len(msg)-1] = '\n'

        // write msg to stream
        _, err = rw.Write(msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing to buffer")
            return err
        }
        err = rw.Flush()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error flushing buffer")
            return err
        }
        return nil
}

func readMsg(rw *bufio.ReadWriter) {
    for {
        // read bytes until new line
        msg, err := rw.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from buffer")
            continue
        }

        // get the id
        id := int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(msg[0:8]))

        // get the content, last index is len(msg)-1 to remove the new line char
        content := string(msg[8:len(msg)-1])

        if content != "" {
            // we print [message ID] content
            fmt.Printf("[%d] %s", id, content)
        }

        // here you could parse your message
        // and prepare a response
        response, err := prepareResponse(content)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Err while preparing response: ", err)
            continue
        }

        if err := s.sendMsg(rw, id, response); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Err while sending response: ", err)
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.